# Can the where statement be written in such a way on repository pattern in php?

Tags: php, laravel, repository-pattern

hi Can this code be refactor?

```
public function all(array $attributes)
    {
        $rates = $this->model->query()->where([
            ['able_type', $attributes['type']],
            ['able_id', $attributes['type_id']]
        ])
            ->get(['rate']);

    return [
        'count' => $rates->count(),
        'average' => $rates->avg('rate')
    ];

}

public function show($attributes)
{
    $result = $this->model->query()->where([
        ['user_id', $attributes['user_id']],
        ['able_type', $attributes['type']],
        ['able_id', $attributes['type_id']]
    ])
        ->first();

    return $result;
}
```

Can the where statement be written in such a way that it does not need to be repeated?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function get(array $attributes)
{
    $rates = $this->model
        ->where('able_type', $attributes['type'])
        ->where('able_id', $attributes['type_id']);

    if(!empty($attributes['user_id']))
    {
        return $rates->where('user_id', $attributes['user_id'])
                     ->first();
    }

    return [
        'count' => $rates->count(),
        'average' => $rates->avg('rate')
    ];
}
```

Handle the both requests in a single function. The code is more neat & clean and easy to read  & understand. Arrow function increase re readability over the arrays.

Comment: I want to separate the where statement that is common to both but i dont know how

Comment: You wanna keep it common?

Comment: Check this:- https://gist.github.com/sahilgupta28/d2e8d993d966755a0ccdce7dc6b32487

Comment: I want to remove all Common methods that have The where method is similar

Comment: have you checked https://gist.github.com/sahilgupta28/d2e8d993d966755a0ccdce7dc6b32487 ?

Comment: I have removed all duplicate values from here. If wanna keep 2 different functions and still there should be no reputation then let me know I'll give you another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor out the common part of the code into a private method, then extend the base with the extra features for each scenario...

```
private function getBase () {
    return $this->model->query()->where([
        ['able_type', $attributes['type']],
        ['able_id', $attributes['type_id']]
    ]);
}

public function all(array $attributes)
{
    $rates = $this->getBase()
        ->get(['rate']);

    return [
        'count' => $rates->count(),
        'average' => $rates->avg('rate')
    ];

}

public function show($attributes)
{
    $result = $this->getBase()
        ->where('user_id', $attributes['user_id'])
        ->first();

    return $result;
}
```

(although I am assuming this will work as I don't code Laravel).